# Homomorphism and the Order of Elements

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

New to forum, and I was hoping you guys would be able to help me out with this problem. The course is abstract algebra.

The problem statement is:

> If *f* : G → H is a homomorphism, prove the following: Let the range of *f* have *m* elements. If *a* ∈ G has order *n*, where *m* and *n* are relatively prime, then *a* is in the kernel of *f*.

I'm at a loss where to begin for this problem.

I know that the range of *f* is a subgroup of H. I know that the order of an element is defined to be the least positive integer n such that $a^n=e$. I know that the kernel of *f* is the set K of all the elements of G are carried by *f* onto the neutral element of H. I just do not know how all these go together to prove the statement.

Thank you!

Comment: Consider the cyclic subgroup $\langle f(a)\rangle < f(G)$. What can its order be, in light of Lagrange's theorem?

Comment: The order must be Prime?

Comment: No not necessarily prime.

Comment: Fortunately, it is not prime in this case, because the problem asks you to prove otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $a^n=e$, we have $e=f(e)=f(a^n)= f(a)^n$. But, $f(a) \in f[G]$, hence the order of $f(a)$ must divide both $m$ and $n$. Hence $f(a)$ has order one, i.e. $f(a)=e$.

Comment: I'm sorry for the silly question but can you let me know what f(a)∈f[G] means? f(a)∈H?

Comment: It means $f(a)\in \{f(x): x\in G\}$.